# How can I print the first column in a text file with each line tabbed in?

Tags: text-processing

This is the text that have in the file:

```
                   1NPD:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  MDVTAKYELIGLMAYPIRHSLSPEMQNKALEKAGLPFTYMAFEVDNDSFPGAIEGLKALKMRGTGVSMPNKQLACEYV
                   1NPD:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  MDVTAKYELIGLMAYPIRHSLSPEMQNKALEKAGLPFTYMAFEVDNDSFPGAIEGLKALKMRGTGVSMPNKQLACEYV
                   1NPY:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  MINKDTQLCMSLSGRPSNFGTTFHNYLYDKLGLNFIYKAFTTQDIEHAIKGVRALGIRGCAVSMPFKETCMPFLDEIH
                   1NPY:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  MINKDTQLCMSLSGRPSNFGTTFHNYLYDKLGLNFIYKAFTTQDIEHAIKGVRALGIRGCAVSMPFKETCMPFLDEIH                       
                   1NPY:C|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  MINKDTQLCMSLSGRPSNFGTTFHNYLYDKLGLNFIYKAFTTQDIEHAIKGVRALGIRGCAVSMPFKETCMPFLDEIH                       
                   1NPY:D|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  MINKDTQLCMSLSGRPSNFGTTFHNYLYDKLGLNFIYKAFTTQDIEHAIKGVRALGIRGCAVSMPFKETCMPFLDEIH                       
                   1NVT:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  GPLGSMINAKTKVIGLIGHPVEHSFSPIMHNAAFKDKGLNYVYVAFDVLPENLKYVIDGAKALGIVGFNVTIPHKIEI                       
                   1NVT:B|PDBID|CHAIN|SEQUENCE  GPLGSMINAKTKVIGLIGHPVEHSFSPIMHNAAFKDKGLNYVYVAFDVLPENLKYVIDGAKALGIVGFNVTIPHKIEI
```

I want to remove the spaces that it has in the beginning, I think there is a tab as well, and I only want to keep the ID which is 1NPD, 1NPY, etc. It doesn't matter if it is A, B or C, I just want one ID of each sequence.

This is how I would like the file to look.

```
1NPD
1NPY
1NVT
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the text you want to process in the file `in.file` and you want to write to a file `out.file`, you can use:

`tr -d ' ' < in.file | cut -d':' -f1 | sort -u > out.file`

The first, removes the spaces from in.file: `tr -d ' ' < in.file`

The second, cuts the text into fields using ':' as the delimiter and selects only the first field: `cut -d':' -f1`

The last, sorts the results, selects the uniques and writes to out.file: `sort -u > out.file`

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with following shell commands:

`sed 's/^[\t ]*//g' /tmp/data|awk -F : '{print $1}'|uniq|tr '\n' ' '`

Remove the tabs and space at beginning, select the first column by awk, then merge the same IDs, using tr to convert multi-lines to one line.

Answer (score 1):

With just `awk`

```
awk -F: '{sub("[ \t]+","",$1)}; !seen[$1]++ {print $1}' textfile
```

- split the text into `:`-delimited fields
- remove leading whitespace from the first field `$1`
- print the trimmed `$1` only the first time you see it

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight simplification of @archemar's answer

```bsh
awk -F'( *|:)' '{print $2}' test.tmp | sort -u
```

The `-F` sets the field separator to a given regular expression, in this case a `:`, or any number of spaces (which makes the leading set of spaces a field separator).  This puts the desired values in column 2.

As in other answers, `sort -u` sorts and ensures uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

in a single awk command

```
 awk '{print substr($1,1,index($1,":")-1)}' in.file | sort -u
```

where

- awk will trim withe space and tab
- `index($1,":")` fetch `:` position
- `substr( )` extract substring
- `sort -u` will ensore uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

With a `grep` implementation with PCRE support:

```
pcregrep -o '^\s*\K[^:]*'
```

Some `grep` implementations have `-P` for PCRE matching, and `-o` for outputting the matched part of the line, though neither are standard options:

```
grep -P '^\s*\K[^:]*'
```

The `\s*` skips the leading (`^`) whitespace, and `\K` *sets* the start of the matched part after it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with sed.  This one uses a backreference in order to replace the input-line with just the id we're interested in:

```bash
$ sed 's/^\s*\(.*\):.*/\1/' your_file | sort -u
1NPD
1NPY
1NVT
```

We are replacing...

- `^\s*` any amount of whitespace at the beginning of the line,
- `\(.*\)` followed by anything (this is `\1` ) that gets followed by...
- `:.*` a colon and then anything.

...with `\1` which is what is between the whitespace and the colon.